# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFlibException' with message 'Couldn't find encoding 'cp936'

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdflib

I encounter this problem

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFlibException' with message 'Couldn't find encoding 'cp936'...

It gives this error when running on the computer that localization is (Chinese RPC), but localization (English) it works fine.

I am using dompdf plugin.

Anyone has idea on how to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font you're trying to use isn't installed on the server, or it doesn't support the extended character set.

Also, for PDF generation, I recommend [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). I'm not sure about CI integration though.